# Integer constant is too large for its type AND invalid operands to binary operators

Tags: c, binary, long-integer, long-double, binary-operators

I'm using `double long` in my 64 bit computer and `sizeof(double long)` is `16 bytes`.
So I do the following assignment:

```
  long double f = 0xA0000000000000000000000000000000; // 32 characters in hex
```

and I get this warning: `warning: integer constant is too large for its type`. That warning doesn't seem correct, my constant can be easily saved in a 128bit value. So, why do I get the warning?

I also have this code:

```
  long double tmp = 0x90000000CCCCCCCC0000000000000000;
  long double res = (f & tmp);  // where f is the previously defined variable
```

and I get the following error `error: invalid operands to binary &`. Why ?

Comment: `long double` is a floating-point type.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean `long long`?

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker `long long` in my 64bit machine is unfortunately a 64bit value, not 128bit as I need. @Mystical seems you are correct that's why `&` doesn't work, but is there perhaps another 128bit type in C that I can use instead?

Comment: Use an array containing two 64 bit ints.

Comment: @FookoR., sorry, miscounted bits. But using floating point should be of little use...

Comment: I would suggest to use [gmp](http://gmplib.org/) for this kind of usage. It's really fast, but requires that you comply to [LGPL](http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/lesser.html)

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> error: invalid operands to binary &
> ```

because `f` and `tmp` are floating point numbers, not integers, they cannot serve as argument to binary `&`.

> ```
> long double f = 0xA0000000000000000000000000000000
> ```

You are initializing a floating-point variable with an integer constant. That is OK per se, but the integer constant has its own type, which can only be as large as the largest integer type you have (the compiler chooses the type that fits). If the largest integer type on your compiler has less than 128 bits, this won't work.

BTW that `sizeof(double long) == 16` doesn't mean that `long double` has 128 bit representation.

Comment: Hm... yes I missed that. Do you perhaps know any other type that has 128bit values other that I Can use it with binary operators? (My `long long` is 64 bits)

Answer (score 1):

Expanding my comment:

`long double` is a floating-point type. That's why you can't do bit-wise operators on them.

Unfortunately, the standard doesn't guarantee a 128-bit integer type. The only compiler I know of that actually supports it as an extension is [GCC via __int128](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fint128.html). (EDIT: It doesn't look it always supports it.)

MSVC also has the `__int128` type, but it remains only reserved and unimplemented.

If you're only doing bit-wise operations, you can use a struct with two 64-bit integers. Or if you're on x86, you can use the 128-bit SSE datatypes.

Comment: About `__int128` it writes: `here is no support in GCC to express an integer constant of type __int128 for targets having long long integer with less then 128 bit width.` . My `long long` is 64 bytes, so it's not supported!

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that. If you want more than bit-wise operators, then you're out of luck unless you find/write a light-weight 128-bit integer library.

Answer (score 1):

`0xA0000000000000000000000000000000` is an integer constant and depending on your system it can be not supported. The larger type for integer constant is `unsigned long long` and if the width of `unsigned long long` is 64-bit in your system, this constant will not fit.

What you can do is to use an **hexadecimal floating constant** instead of an hexadecimal integer constant.

```
long double f = 0xA0000000000000000000000000000000p0L;
                                                  ^^ the exponent is 0
```

is OK.

The `p` introduces the exponent (required) and the `L` indicates it is a `long double` literal (default is `double`).

Hexadecimal floating constant is a C99 addition and note that in hexadecimal floating constants the exponent part is required.

Regarding bitwise operators (the second part of your question), the operands of bitwise operators must be of integer types so you cannot perform bitwise operations on floating-point values.